# is there any nice way to step back in an activiti workflow task?

Tags: business-process-management, activiti

I am using activiti bpm engine to control my workflow. Is it posible to step back if I made mistake in chioce? if no, what should be done? Must I complete the workflow and start a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'going back' in workflow, it's well against.. the flow ;) If you wan't to give user the possibility to 'step back' you can model additional flows again to the same task which has been just completed.