# Sendback to already completed Task of processInstance in Activiti

Tags: activiti

How can I send back to a task which is marked as complete in a process instance.I am trying to use activiti engine APIs to achieve that but could not find any directly.

I was expecting something like

```
processEngine.getTaskService().sendBack(task.getId());
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193831/is-there-any-nice-way-to-step-back-in-an-activiti-workflow-task

Comment: You can not go back to last task completed, as `activiti engine` won't allow that, i think no BPM engine allow it. But if you want to get what is the last task completed, then you can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding sequence flow to every other step with an exclusive gateway and a conditional expression sendback is achievable.